# Java Sockets, java.net.SocketException: Connection reset, because of BufferedWriter/Reader?

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedwriter

This is just a very Simple Server/Client application that i have written in Java with the intention using BufferedReader and BufferedWriter only.
I dont get any Errors when i start the Server.

But when the Client tries to send a message to the server:

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

appears. I dont know why this happens but i think it could have to do something with the BufferedWriter maybe.
I searched in the Internet but i haven't found anything usefull specific to this.

**Server.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server {
    public Server(int port) {
        try {
            ServerSocket seso = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Server started");
            System.out.println("Server listening on port " + port);

            Socket client1 = seso.accept();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client1.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client1.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));

            String s = null;

            while((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Client: " + s);
            }

            writer.close();
            reader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Server(4444);
    }
}
```

**Client.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client {
    public Client(String serverip) {
        try {
            Socket client = new Socket(serverip, 4444);
            System.out.println("Client connected with: " + serverip);

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));

            writer.write("Hello Server");
            writer.flush();

        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Client("localhost");
    }
}
```

And when i run the server followed by the client i get this from the console:

```
Server started
Server listening on port 4444

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
at Server.<init>(Server.java:24)
at Server.main(Server.java:33)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 9 seconds)
```

If i add:

```
writer.newLine();
```

after

```
writer.write("Hello Server");
```

in **Client.java** i still get:

```
Server started
Server listening on port 4444
Client: Hello Server

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
at Server.<init>(Server.java:24)
at Server.main(Server.java:33)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Comment: You are not closing the Socket or the streams cleanly in your client.

Comment: yes, and you are not sending a '\n', so the server's read hangs.

Comment: To be exact, you didn't close the socket and you ran the client on Windows (but didn't say so). A Windows process (Java or other) terminating without closing its open TCP socket causes an 'abnormal termination' aka reset of the connection, which for a Java peer results in the exception you got, but doing the same thing on Unix does not.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Do you have an idea how to close the Sockets/Streams correctly?

Comment: ok i've solved the problem, thanks to you all :).

Comment: how did you solve the problem. can you please help me. I am also facing the same